# Postgres full text search dictionary strip special charachters

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-14

I'm using postgres full text search for (amoung other things) to provide autocomplete functionality for usernames and tags.  However, I'd like autocomplete to match the column value 'dashed-tag-example' against a ts_query like 'dashedtag:*'.

My understanding is that, to do this without duplicating the column in my table I need to create a dictionary along the lines of the simple dictionary that strips charachters like '-'.  Is it possible to create such a dictionary using SQL (i.e. something I could put in a rails migration)?

It seems like it should somehow be possible to define a dictionary (or do I need a parser?) that uses postgres's regexp substition functions but I can't seem to find any examples online of how to create a dictionary (parser?) like that.  Is this possible?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is too late; you would need a different parser, which would require writing C code.

The simple and pragmatic solution is to use `replace()` to strip the `-` when you construct the `tsvector`.

You don't need to create a new column for that, simply search like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE to_tsvector('english', replace(col, '-', ''))
      @@ to_tsquery('english', replace('search-string', '-' ''));
```

Comment: But that would mean creating another column correct?  Suppose I have a column tagname with entries like 'full-text-search' but I want to match that with a prefix search 'fulltex'.  I'd need to create a column like 'normalized_tagname' and search against that no?

Comment: So far my hacky solution has been to use the unaccent extension and created a ruleset that simply deletes the dashes.  However, that's annoying in that I have to go install the ruleset in the postgres directory when I deploy.  I feel like I'm overcomplicating things but not sure.

Comment: Ohh wait?  Can I use replace in the definition of the GIN index?

I'm pretty sure I can't (and even if I could then I could no longer have a different search config that didn't ignore - when consulting that column no?).  So I'm guessing my unaccent solution is the best I can do.

Comment: Sure you can use `replace` in an index definition, since it is immutable. You could have two indexes on the column for two different searches.

Comment: I think I'm pretty confused then.  If I try to match 'fulltex' against 'full-text-search' then, even if I used replace in my index definition, won't postgres throw out 'full-text-search' as a match when it actually loads the row if the full text search config doesn't say to ignore dashes?  I thought indexes only affected speed and never result sets.

Comment: That is correct. But if you look at my edited answer, I changed the query so that it also uses `replace`.

Comment: Ohh, I see now how it works.  Now my sql query is asking to find a column where calling replace on both sides gives a match.  Thanks so much that's exactly what I needed.  Doubt pg_search gem will recognize that but it's a simple enough search so I'll just drop back to just doing it directly in SQL.  Thanks so much!!